# How to disable bounds on fluid sim?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'd like to know how to make a fluid simulation where the domain does not act like a wall. In the smoke sim, you can enable smoke to pass out of the domain, but how do you do this in the fluid sim? To be clear, I don't want the fluid to drain out of the domain, but act as if there is more beyond the domain, like the simulation is part of a large body of water.

Comment: I don't think that you can make the domain object an "outflow". Bt maybe you could make an outflow object just inside the domain object?

Comment: But wont then the fluid drain away? I want to make the sim open ended, like it's part of an ocean.

Comment: Well the domain will have to be as large as you want the volume of water to be to be. The reason for having a domain is to constrain the memory and processing time. Sorry.